# how to get deepest element of a JSONArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

how to get deepest array of a json array in java android ?

Array
(

[0] => Array

```
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => and
                [2] => 2
            )

        [1] => or
        [2] => 3
    )

[1] => and
[2] => 2
```

)

in this case I want get elem[0][0]
or

Array

```
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => and
  [2] => 2
)
```

Comment: json encoded is : [[[1,"and",2],"or",3],"and",2]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I think this need a recursive method but how !

Comment: what is unclear in `JSONArray` API documentation?

Comment: my problem is JSONArray decodes array in only one level

Comment: and what does `JSONArray#get(int index)` return?

Comment: its return a string

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know exactly what you’re trying to do, but maybe this could shed some light on your question:

```
JSONArray findDeepestArray(JSONArray arr){
    for(Object o : arr){
        if(o instanceof JSONArray){
            JSONArray ob = (JSONArray) o;
            JSONArray a = findDeepestArray(ob);
            return null != a ? a : ob;
        }
    }
}
```

Please, adapt it to your needs, this is just a rough draft.

Hope it helps.